# ConnectionResetError while running through cron

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I'm sending a simple 'post' request through the 'requests' module. It works fine when execute it directly through the linux terminal. However, when I set it up through the crontab, the log is indicating and error.

- If I execute the below through the terminal, it works fine.

> '/usr/bin/python3.6 /location/sa/tb/uc/md/se/sea.py'

- If I setup the crontab as follows, I get an error.

> - - - - - /usr/bin/python3.6 /location/sa/tb/uc/md/se/sea.py >> ~/Test_log.log 2>&1

- Below is the error message:

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 600, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 343, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 839, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line
> 344, in connect
> ssl_context=context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py", line
> 345, in ssl_wrap_socket
> return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
> _context=self, _session=session)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 776, in **init**
> self.do_handshake()   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1036, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 648, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

**What did I try?**

- Tried adding absolute path inside the script.
- Added a proxy to the headers, but no go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For first time execution, the error given is ```[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer```. Is further request errors are ```[Errno 32] Broken pipe```?

Comment: The further error is:
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Answer (score 0):

Some servers don't start re-listen immediately (`check_mk` flag), while calling multiple requests from a single connection. One of the reason is to avoid DoS attacks and service availability to all users.

Since your crontab made your script to call the same API multiple times using a single connection, I'd suggest you to add a void timer before making a request, e.g. add `time.sleep(0.01)` just before calling the API.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried it; but didn't work. Maybe it's our server thing that cron setup for external calls has this issue. Any other suggestion is welcome.